# Type mismatch on subscription with RxJava

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

I have the following code to get a sliding window average. I am getting a type mismatch error in the subscribe function. I am trying to get the average of cpu Usage using the RxMath Average Function.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import rx.*;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.functions.Action1;
import rx.functions.Func1;
import rx.observables.MathObservable;

public class stack {
    private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executorPool;

    public void test() {
        Double tests = (double) 100;

        Observable myObservable = Observable.interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .map(new Func1<Long, Double>() {
                    @Override
                    public Double call(Long aLong) {
                        Double d = (double) 100;//calculate CPU usage                             
                        return d;
                    }
                })
                .window(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMap(new Func1<Observable<Double>, Observable<Double>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Double> call(Observable<Double> windowObservable) {
                        return MathObservable.averageDouble(windowObservable);
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(new Action1<Double>() {
                    public void call(Double s) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you want to assign the result of subscribe() to an Observable which are incompatible. Either assign it to a Subscription, stop the expression before the subscribe and in a new statement, call myObservable.subscribe(...)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `Observable myObservable =` from the beginning.

`subscribe` is returning a `Subscription`, not an `Observable`. In your case, you don't need to remember a reference to the `Observable`.

If you ever do, follow this pattern:

```
Observable<Double> myObservable = stuffThatReturnsAnObservable();
Subscription subscription = myObservable.subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Rob mentioned in your case you don't even need a reference to the subscription since all you're doing is passing an action to it on subscription. Having a reference to a subscription allows you to unsubscribe from it which will stop sending you events.